# Resource throttling and LINQ / spmetal

Tags: 2010, linq, spmetal

Today I received an e-mail from a customer telling me their site broke. I checked the ULS and noticed resource throttling had kicked in on one of the sites. I'm used to this when using SPSiteDataQuery, but this time I'd created an spmetal definition of my list and used that to query it.

Apparantly, the LINQ queries are handled with throttling limits as well. But on the SPSiteDataQuery there was an override option to switch it off. I was looking for the same thing for a LINQ query / context, but that doesn't seem to exist. Anyone knows if it's possible to override the throttling when using LINQ queries?